# Pass a null date to a crystal report parameter using SetParameterValue

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a situation where I have a crystal report where I pass in a start and end date via `rdoc.SetParameterValue` this works fine, except that, I do not want it to show a date if I pass nothing for the date variable, I just want it to be blank

To an attempt to do so i have written

```
    if (DateStart != defaultDate)
    {
        rdoc.SetParameterValue("DStart", DateStart);
    }else
    {
        rdoc.SetParameterValue("DStart", "");
    }
```

Which gives me the error `The types of the parameter field and parameter field current values are not compatible` of course, this makes sense because I am trying to set a date to a string variable. 
However, I am unable to think of a solution, nor do I see any solution in the Parameter's menu.

Appreciate it if I be given some assistance to solve this.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may change the parameter type to string and pass the date as string:

```
DateStart.ToString()
```

I don't like this solution, but it works. Usually i just require the date.